# CAML query for boolean column is not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

Hi I have a SharePoint list to be queried for my Desktop App and I want to retrieve only the Active Members but when I queried I got only the users who aren't active. What is wrong with my CAML query?

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<<"View">><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'> " + true + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"";
```

I tried the following as well

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'> true</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

and

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'> true</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
```

Please help as I'm new to CAML.

Comment: Try to search in google, there is a lot samples of caml query in sharepoint. Things that you have written doesn't look like caml query

Comment: For some reason that I don't know, I'm sure that sharepoint has a bug, because I have two boolean columns configured by the same way (column "Returned" and column "Checked") and if I use a CAML code to query the spList by the column "Returned" it works, but when I JUST change this CAML code to query by the other column "Checked", just changing the attribute name to the column "Checked", where we set the internal field name only, the code doesn't bring me any spListitem as result, but it should return some items.
very weird Column "A" (Returned) <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Returned'/><Value Type

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Save yourself some grief and use a tool to help build up CAML queries such as [U2U's Caml Query Builder.](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlQueryBuilder.aspx)

You need to use 1 and 0 (not true and false) in the query, so

```
<Query><Where>
   <Eq><FieldRef Name="Active" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq>
</Where></Query>
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, for some Boolean columns you have to put value as "true" and not "1" - I am yet to figure out why

Comment: If you keep Type="Integer", you will always have to use 1 and 0

Answer (score 2):

This Works for me

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View>" + "<Query>" + "<Where>" + "<Eq>" +
"<FieldRef Name='Active'/>" + " <Value Type='Boolean'>" + "1" + "</Value>" +
"</Eq>" + "</Where>" + "</Query>" + "</View>";
```

Comment: Why do you concatenate the query string like this?

Comment: @Patric I was taught to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value type `Bool` and it works with "true", "True" or "TRUE"

Comment: I do't think such type exists, can you post link to documentation showing it?

Comment: Just use this method via Caml Query Builder and it work just fine!

Comment: Heh, it really works. And looks like it is a better option as it takes 1, true, True and TRUE while Boolean only 1. Tested on SP Online